# creating a call back function after a successfull windows.location.href call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

So i have a function as such:

```
$("#MyButton").on("click", function () {
    // build up a parameter list from a Kendo Grid

    window.location.href = "/Controller/ActionMethodName?Parameters=" + MyParameters;

    $("#MyKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```

Everything processes great and even returns a csv (excel file).   Only thing is my Kendo Grid doesn't read (refresh).   I somehow need to put MyKendoGrid to a callback function to run only after my window.location.href is run.   Any help or ideas with this would be appreciated..

Comment: `location.href` redirects to a new page. Any code after that is pointless since your no longer on that page.

Comment: What if i'm not redirecting to a new page,  i'm on the same page  but i'm just using windows.location.href to call an action method..

Comment: Is the purpose of the action to create a file download or something?  You mentioned a csv file.

Comment: `windows.location.href` makes a redirect. If you want to call a method that returns a result and update the existing page, then you need to use ajax

Comment: Yes the purpose is to return a file.  A csv file.  Only problem with using Jquery AJAX is that it doesn't allow for the return of Files.

Comment: you can open a new window with that url ? (`window.open` method)

Comment: There is a kendo.saveAS method and i already know how to create the csv in my Action,  just not sure how to return it from the action

Comment: ^^^ or a hidden iframe could be used for this purpose, of which since it's the same domain you could attach an on load event handler to.